# error Command failed with signal "SIGBUS"

Tags: next.js, server, sigbus

I am a junior and still new to server or building a site. And now I am trying to build a next.js project on a server, it builds well until it says `Creating an optimized production build...`, then this error occurs `error Command failed with signal "SIGBUS".`I have made some research on what BUS error is but still it's really hard for me to work on fixing the error.
Any help or suggestion of what to do will be so well appreciated. Thank you

I haven't tried any command to solve this yet as I am not so familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then `npm install` again was the solution to this issue.